# After update trigger in postgresql not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Created below trigger in postgresql(to do same logic as of sqlserver trigger defined in below code)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lookup_dbo.finlstatassetdesignation(
    finlstatassetdesignation CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    finlstatassetdesignationdesc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    updoperation NUMERIC(5,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    upddate TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()
);
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TR_FinlStatAssetDesignation_U_TrFunc()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE  plpgsql
   AS $$
   DECLARE
   AtDateTime  TIMESTAMP;
   SWV_error INTEGER;
   SWV_RowCount INTEGER;
BEGIN
   SWV_error := 0;
   GET DIAGNOSTICS SWV_RowCount = ROW_COUNT;
   IF (SWV_RowCount = 0) then 
      RETURN NULL;
   end if;                                  
   AtDateTime := LOCALTIMESTAMP;                                    

   if OLD.FinlStatAssetDesignation IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.FinlStatAssetDesignation then

      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid attempt to update OID FinlStatAssetDesignation in FinlStatAssetDesignation';
      -- Rollback 
      RETURN NULL;
   end if;                                      

   if not OLD.UpdDate IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.UpdDate then

      SWV_error := 0;
      begin
         UPDATE lookup_dbo.finlstatassetdesignation
         SET UpdDate = AtDateTime
         WHERE a.FinlStatAssetDesignation = NEW.FinlStatAssetDesignation;
         EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            SWV_error := -1;
            RETURN NULL;
      end;
      if SWV_error <> 0 then

         -- RollBack 
         RETURN NULL;
      end if;

      SWV_error := 0;
   end if;

   RETURN NULL;
   END; $$;
```

```
CREATE Trigger tr_finlstatassetdesignation_u
    AFTER Update on lookup_dbo.finlstatassetdesignation FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE lookup_dbo.tr_finlstatassetdesignation_u_trfunc();
```

SQL Server original trigger code:-

```
-- Add Update Trigger to FinlStatAssetDesignation                                       
CREATE Trigger TR_FinlStatAssetDesignation_U on FinlStatAssetDesignation for Update NOT FOR REPLICATION as                                      
    IF (@@RowCount = 0) return                                  
    DECLARE @AtDateTime datetime                                    

    SELECT @AtDateTime = GETDATE()                                  

if Update(FinlStatAssetDesignation)                                     
Begin                                       
    RaisError( 'Invalid attempt to update OID FinlStatAssetDesignation in FinlStatAssetDesignation', 16, 1 )                                    
    Rollback Tran                                   
    return                                  
end                                     


if not Update(UpdDate)                                      
begin                                       
    Update a                                    
    set UpdDate = @AtDateTime                                   
    from FinlStatAssetDesignation a, Inserted i                                 
    where a.FinlStatAssetDesignation = i.FinlStatAssetDesignation                                   
    if @@ERROR<>0                                   
    begin                                   
        RollBack tran                               
        return/* Execution stops here! */                               
    end                                 
end                                     
go
```

The converted trigger in postgresql and even original sqlserver one has 2 parts...for first one..it seems working post conversion in postgresql however second part seems not working...please help

Comment: Why are you commenting the `return null;` with `-- rollback`? Returning `NULL` from an **AFTER** trigger won't change anything, let alone cause a rollback. If you want to prevent the DML statement from doing anything you need a `BEFORE` trigger. Only there returning `NULL` will change the outcome of the triggering statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name..uncommenting it out then..but second part of my code is still not updating upddate column with timestamp

Comment: If you want to change values in the updated (or inserted) row do not use an AFTER trigger. Use a BEFORE trigger and simply assign the new value: `new.update := current_timestamp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent certain updates and want to change the values of the update (or inserted) row, do not use an AFTER trigger. Use a `BEFORE` trigger and simply assign the value you want. Additionally you can't really stop the UPDATE in an AFTER trigger.

Checking for the number of affected rows is completely useless in a row level trigger. *If* the trigger is fired that number is **always** `1`.

If I understand your intentions correctly, your simplified code should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tr_finlstatassetdesignation_u_trfunc()
   RETURNS TRIGGER 
   LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$
BEGIN
   if old.finlstatassetdesignation IS DISTINCT FROM new.finlstatassetdesignation then
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid attempt to update FinlStatAssetDesignation in FinlStatAssetDesignation';
      -- Rollback 
      RETURN NULL;
   end if;                                      

   if not old.upddate IS DISTINCT FROM new.upddate then
     new.upddate := clock_timestamp();  
   end if;

   -- this is important in a BEFORE trigger!
   RETURN new;
END
$$;
```

Together with the following trigger definition:

```
CREATE Trigger tr_finlstatassetdesignation_u
    BEFORE Update on lookup_dbo.finlstatassetdesignation 
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE lookup_dbo.tr_finlstatassetdesignation_u_trfunc();
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/EWILW61724

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name...my apologies for creating confusion...i just pasted original sql server code which i converted to sqlserver...so as to make things easier for you all to understand.....i want the same logic of sqlserver trigger(pasted above) in postgresql...it seems to be after update trigger only

Comment: @rock_techie: so what "logic" is that? The only thing I can see is to update the column `upddate` and to prevent changes to `finlstatassetdesignation`. If that indeed is the complete logic there is no way to replicate the complexity of a T-SQL trigger to Postgres. The code in my answer will do **exactly** that. If there is more logic hidden in your code you need to explain what it is.  SQL Server has no concept of a "before" trigger let alone a row level trigger. It is as simple as it look in Postgres. No need to over complicate things

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name....yes that is the only SQLSERVER Code logic which i pasted above....my intention is to replicate the same in postgresql.....which you confirmed your code would do the same in posgresql....however i still have 1 doubt...how do i test the column upddate updated with new timestamp i.e test second part of this trigger myself?

Comment: @rock_techie why do you want to replicate something that is uselessly inefficient in Postgres? If you use an UPDATE statement in an AFTER trigger you are essentially updating the same row **twice** each time you change it. That is inefficient and slow. _Assigning_ the new value is the correct and efficient way to do this in Postgres. You have to learn that Postgres is massively different to SQL Server and things are done differently there. Insisting on doing things the "Microsoft way" in Postgres will only leave you with a slow system and unmaintainable code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name...http://rextester.com/JIUZGS76155 please check my output...it updates column directly too

Comment: @rock_techie: but isn't that your "logic"? If the `upddate` column is **not** changed by the update statement, then the trigger should update it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name...yes indeed...however in your example..."-- nothing will change if the column is updated directly".........this is not correct as it is allowing me to change column upddate directly

Comment: @rock_techie: but that's what your T-SQL code is doing. The `if not Update(UpdDate)  then` has no `else` part which means that _if_ the column was changed explicitly in the UPDATE statement your original trigger will not change it either.

Comment: I see thanks but i just wanted to get your example updated..thanks much for your help

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS SWV_RowCount = ROW_COUNT;
IF (SWV_RowCount = 0) THEN 
   RETURN NULL;
END IF;
```

Since you execute this at the beginning of the function and there was no prior SQL statement *in the function*, the value will always be zero, and the trigger will exit immediately.

You seem to assume that `ROW_COUNT` will contain the number of rows modified in the statement that triggered the function, but that is not the case. It contains the number of rows modified by the last SQL statement *in that function itself*.

You can just remove this check. The trigger function will be called for each row that is modified, so it will not be called at all if not a single row is modified.

Finally, it is a good habit to `RETURN NEW;` from a trigger function, unless you have a good reason to prevent the execution of other `AFTER UPDATE` triggers on that function.

Comment: Laurenz Albe@Thanks first part of trigger worked with exception one but second one is not working...please see above edited output

Comment: I think the recommended way is this: 1) you revert your edit on the question that made my answer meaningless 2) you open a new question for the second problem.

Comment: laurenz@ I think original code(trigger) was not working as expected which had 2 parts...that is what and when i originally posted this question...it had both of the 2 parts...so it was solved partially with your help....had to edit the code as best practice since cant do in comments section...I would have posted a new question if trigger would have something new...

Comment: The problem is that your edit made my answer useless. I'm not willing to play moving targets. I'm happy if you edit the question so that the original function code is there, and both parts of the question clearly visible.

Comment: Laurenz@ I just edited it back with original code...can anyone help on second part now?

Comment: @rock_techie: in addition to what Laurenz wrote in his answer: you are creating a **row level** trigger. So the number of affected rows inside the trigger is always exactly 1, not 0 not 3 not anything else. If there wasn't an affected row, the trigger wouldn't have fired. There is no need to check the "row count"

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name@thanks got it...however still stuck on second part of the trigger...can you help?

Comment: Can you clean up the code a little? It looks like the same function is defined twice. Also, what exactly is behaving different from what you expect? Please try to make it easy for me.

Comment: @laurenz...just did the update..second part of the trigger which should update the upddate column with timestamp doesnt seems to be working

Comment: Please restore the UPDTEs and SELECTs that demonstrate what is not working.